# relativelyprime number matrix

Tags: java, matrix, boolean

i want to create a NxN matrix that takes N from the command line matrix such that the
element in row i and column j (1 ≤ i, j ≤ N) is a "*" (a star) if i and j are relatively
prime (ie, GCD(i, j) = 1) and " " (a space) otherwise. The row numbers should be
printed at the end of each row.

```
public static boolean[][] relativelyPrime(int N) {
boolean[][] array = new boolean [N+1][N+1];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if ( 1 <= i && i <= N && 1 <= j && j <= N) {
           if (gcd(i,j) == 1){
              return array;
           }
        }
    }
}
return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
boolean[][] matrix = relativelyPrime(N);
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length: j++) {
        if (1 <= i && i <= N && 1 <= j && j <= N) {
           if (gcd(i, j) == 1) { System.out.println("*" + i);
            }
           else { System.out.println(" " + i);
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

i am trying to create a matrix that looks like this:

```
* * * * * * * * * * 1
*   *   *   *   *   2
* *   * *   * *   * 3
*   *   *   *   *   4
* * * *   * * * *   5
*       *   *       6
* * * * * *   * * * 7
*   *   *   *   *   8
* *   * *   * *   * 9
*   *       *   *   10
```

but im getting

```
*1
*1
*1
*1
*1
*1
*1
*1
*1
*1
*2
 2
*2
 2
.
.
.
```

how do i put this in a matrix

Answer (score 1):

You should use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 11;
    boolean[][] matrix = relativelyPrime(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            if (1 <= i && i <= N && 1 <= j && j <= N) {
               if (gcd(i, j) == 1) { System.out.print("*");
                }
               else { System.out.print(" ");
                }
             }
         }
        System.out.println(i);
     }
    }
```

In this case, it will give you zero at the first line, to eliminate this use additional if statement:

```
         }
       if(i!=0)
        System.out.println(i);
   }
```